# is there fcgi-api for php?

Tags: php, api, fastcgi

Im not meaning "using apache2/nginx with FCGI" but, api for waiting for incoming FCGI connection like FCGI api written in C or Java, which create the environment, and support stream to client etc.

Is FCGI-API implemented?

edit:
Or is there a documentation about protocol definition, to i can write?

Comment: I meant a utility where after I bind a port and accept a connection (in PHP) I give to this utility and its can parse the incoming FCGI protocol data and provides an input and output stream from/to the client (over the original connection)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, your question isn't exactly clear on what you're looking for.

There is a build of php: php-cgi  That can handle the requests.  You'll need something like php-fpm or spawn cgi to handle the multiple requests.
http://php-fpm.org/
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi/wiki

Usually the webserver forwards the requests to those applications and they spawn php instances as needed.  There is no requirement that the webserver be on the same box.  They usually listen through a unix socket or through port 9000

The actually specification can be found here:
http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html

There is also some php cgi info here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php